# Windows Store App - C# - How to handle multi threaded application debug logging

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, logging, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to write a log class to log to a file, however I keep getting issues with the logging due to different threads trying to log at the same time.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Log.Diag.<DebugPrint>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Here is my code:

```
        public static async void DebugPrint(string msg, LogLevel level)
    {
        if (ShouldLog(level))
        {
#if DEBUG
            // Only do this in debug
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
#endif
#if !DEBUG // Never crash in release build
            try
            {
#endif
                if (sFile == null && !(await GetLogFile()))
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot create ms-appdata:///local/log.txt");
                }
                try
                {
                        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(sFile, ComposeMessage(msg, level));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
#if !DEBUG
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
#endif
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise the log file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async static Task<bool> GetLogFile()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            sFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("log.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What can I do to ensure that all threads can log to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it using event tracing.

Task.cs

```
sealed class LogEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static LogEventSource Log = new LogEventSource();

    [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.LogAlways)]
    public void Debug(string message)
    {
        this.WriteEvent(1, message);
    }
}

/// <summary> 
/// Storage event listner to do thread safe logging to a file.
/// </summary> 
sealed class StorageFileEventListener : EventListener
{
    private object syncObj = new object();
    private List<string> logLines;
    private StorageFile logFile;
    private ThreadPoolTimer periodicTimer;

    public StorageFileEventListener()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("StorageFileEventListener for {0}", GetHashCode());
        logLines = new List<string>();
    }
    // Should be called right after the constructor (since constructors can't have async calls)
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        logFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("logs.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        // We don't want to write to disk every single time a log event occurs, so let's schedule a
        // thread pool task
        periodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
        {
            // We have to lock when writing to disk as well, otherwise the in memory cache could change
            // or we might try to write lines to disk more than once
            lock (syncObj)
            {
                if (logLines.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Write synchronously here. We'll never be called on a UI thread and you
                    // cannot make an async call within a lock statement
                    FileIO.AppendLinesAsync(logFile, logLines).AsTask().Wait();
                    logLines = new List<string>();
                }
            }
            CheckLogFile();

        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }


    private async void CheckLogFile()
    {

        BasicProperties p = await logFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        if(p.Size > (1024 * 1024))
        {
            // TODO: Create new log file and compress old.
        }
    }

    protected override void OnEventWritten(EventWrittenEventArgs eventData)
    {
        // This could be called from any thread, and we want our logs in order, so lock here
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            logLines.Add((string)eventData.Payload[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

Wrapped in a logging class.

```
/// <summary>
/// A static class for help with debugging and logging.
/// </summary>
public static class Log
{
    public enum LogLevel {
        NONE = 0,
        FATAL,
        ERROR,
        INFO,
        DEBUG,
        VERBOSE,
        TRACE
    };

    private static StorageFileEventListener eventListener;
#if DEBUG
    public static LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.DEBUG;
#else
    public static LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.NONE;
#endif
    /// <summary>
    /// Print out the debug message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg">Message to print</param>
    /// <param name="level">Debug level of message</param>
    public async static void DebugPrint(string msg, LogLevel level)
    {
        if (ShouldLog(level))
        {
            msg = ComposeMessage(msg, level);
#if DEBUG
            // Only do this in debug
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
#endif
#if !DEBUG // Never crash in release build
            try
            {
#endif
                if (eventListener == null)
                {
                    eventListener = new StorageFileEventListener();
                    eventListener.EnableEvents(LogEventSource.Log, EventLevel.LogAlways);
                    await eventListener.InitializeAsync();
                }
                LogEventSource.Log.Debug(msg);
#if !DEBUG
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
#endif
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Construc the formatted log message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg">Main message</param>
    /// <param name="level">Log level</param>
    /// <returns>Formated message</returns>
    private static string ComposeMessage(string msg, LogLevel level)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString(@"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt") + " [" + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId.ToString("X4") + "] " + LevelToString(level) + " " + msg;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the string alias for a log level.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The log level</param>
    /// <returns>String representation of the log level.</returns>
    private static string LevelToString(LogLevel level)
    {
        string res = "NOT FOUND";
        switch (level)
        {
            case LogLevel.NONE:
                throw new Exception("You should not log at this level (NONE)");
            case LogLevel.FATAL: res = "FATAL"; break;
            case LogLevel.ERROR: res = "ERROR"; break;
            case LogLevel.INFO: res = "INFO"; break;
            case LogLevel.DEBUG: res = "DEBUG"; break;
            case LogLevel.VERBOSE: res = "VERBOSE"; break;
            case LogLevel.TRACE: res = "TRACE"; break;
        }
        return res;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check the passed log level against the current log level 
    /// to see if the message should be logged.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">Log level to check against</param>
    /// <returns>True is should be logeed otherwise false.</returns>
    private static bool ShouldLog(LogLevel level)
    {
        if (level <= logLevel)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Log.DebugPrint("Hello, Thread safe logger!", Log.LogLevel.DEBUG);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid concurrency issues you need to use [locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

Comment: But it doesn't look like you can `await` in a `lock` statement. I'm writing to the file asynchronosly

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to write all the messages into a queue and use a background thread to write the queue into the file. This has many advantages:

- easy to make it multithreading saving. Just lock every access to the queue
- only 1 thread writing to the file => no more multi threading problems
- Adding to the queue is very fast (microseconds) and will hardly lock, while writing to the file does not just create multi threading problems, but might create milliseconds delays or even exceptions.
- The logging can start right from the first line of code. Messages are written into the queue, which will only get emptied once file system is ready

Comment: [That is how I did it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22782466/655703). Though you shouldn't do it on a background task, as it can only use [2s of CPU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx) time before your app gets killed.

Comment: After reading your comment, I went through your code again. I can guess that it might be the same approach. Using event listener obscures how simple and elegant the solution actually could be. I guess my answer can be easier understood, but it is always good to have also some working code like in your answer.

Comment: As far as I know, the only difference between a background thread and a normal thread is that a program can shut down when the background thread is still running, whereas a normal thread needs to be stopped before the program can shut down. In production code, I probably would ensure that the file is properly closed and end the thread. Your link is about background task, which is not the same as a background thread. A background thread has no 2 second limit.

Comment: I can only assume you are referring to developing a desktop application and not a windows store app. I suggest you read the documentation and actually write a windows store app to test your theory. Seeing as you have posted no code, I can only assume that your answer,  is just a theory.